# Zend Framework - Route: Call action by param

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

```
$router->addRoute('routeName', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'test/:category/', array(
        'module'      => 'default',
        'controller'  => 'test',
        'action'      => ':category'
    )
));
```

That's my code at the moment (see above). How could I call now the action by a given param (via URL)? The url look e.g. like that: `domain.com/test/news/` and now I want to call the action newsAction() in the test controller. With the code above I get the error: `Action "category" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is useless. The goal you want to achieve is exactly how the standard route works.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply use :action in your route.  Alternatively, you could use a custom __call() method in your controller to catch dynamic action names.